# Do Nlog(logN), NlogN, Nlog(N^2) have equivalent running times?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, performance

I think NlogN and Nlog(N^2) are equivalent, and Nlog(logN) has a better RT than NlogN and Nlog(N^2).
Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Big O notation has nothing to do with actual run time.  O(n) can run shorter than O(1) for a given `n` value depending on the actual implementation.

Big O notation is about comparing how algorithms *scale*.  Meaning as `n` increases, how much do they change relative to each other.

So, an example:

```
function add100(x) {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}

function twice(x) {
    tmp = x;
    for (i = 0; i < tmp; i++) {
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I know these functions can be reduced to `x+100` and `2 * x` respectively, but for demonstration purposes they are simple and show what we want them to. (and some compilers may actually optimize them, so there may not be a difference depending on your environment).

Now, `add100(x)` has an algorithmic complexity of `O(1)`.  And `double(x)` has a complexity of `O(n)`.  However, for values of `x` < 100, `twice(x)` will be faster than `add100(x)`.  For arbitrary input it won't.  It won't scale as well, but it *is* faster for some range of input.  Now, this is a trivial implementation, and not all algorithms will have a *faster* input range, but it does demonstrate that `O()` notation has no effect on actual runtime...

However, in this particular case, it's simple [logarithm math](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules.htm).  So `Log(m^n) == n * Log(m)`, therefore `n log(n) == log(n^n)`. So `n log(n) != n log(n^2)`...  However, since constants are dropped in big O notation, `n log (n^2)` will transform to `2n log (n)` which transforms to `n log (n)`...  So `n log(n) == n log(n^2)` **for the purposes of Big O notation**...

Comment: +1 for the explicit "Big O has nothing to do with actual run time" comment. The key word here is the "actual" part. Big O is great for analysis and conjecture, and certainly you can *base* design decisions off Big O, but the only way to really know equivalent running times is by implementing and profiling the algorithms.

Comment: If you have a few hours to kill.  These lectures cover the subject quite well. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpRRUQFbePU

Answer (score 11):

```
N*log(N^2) = 2N*log(N)
```

`2N*log(N)` is equivalent to `N*log(N)` (when it comes to big O notation, constant is skipped). `NLog(logN)` grows slower (has better runtime performance for growing N).

Answer (score 1):

Since log(n^2) = 2log(n), n*log(n^2) = 2n*log(n), which is equivalent to n*log(n).

And log(log(n)) < log(n), so n*log(log(n) < n*log(n).

You should just trust the basic properties of the logarithm function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right if you are comparing in big O notation.  Using the properties of logarithms, log n^2 == 2 * log n, so they are equivalent in big O.  The log log n function grows strictly more slowly than log n.